# How to copy (synchronize) data from any Stack Exchange site to an OSQA site?

Tags: support

We have finalized and setup our brand new AnswerHub site for Bitcoin Q&A at http://bitcoineer.com, but how can we synchronize open data sources into our open OSQA site.

We want to be a central repository specifically for Bitcoin questions and answers, but we don't want to be left out in the cold. From what I understand there are XML-style feeds and APIs like for Stack Exchange to import/export our site data.

What are the tools we need?

Can someone recommend a list of datapoints to work with for bitcoins?

Can we sync http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com with our site? This would be not just messages, but users, badges, scores, etc.

The idea we have would be to reward users with bitcoins to answer questions about bitcoins.

Comment: Let me understand, you make a clone site and now you won to clone the data too ?

Comment: "We want to be a central repository specifically for Bitcoin question/answer." - don't we already have that? (bitcoin.stackexchange.com)

Comment: I'm not so sure why this got the reception it did, with _proper attribution_ I don't see what's the problem. You can start reading about the SE API here: http://api.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Aristos There is no inherent problem with either those things. Attribution required, but when done well there's no problem.

Comment: "Another" OSQA site? SE isn't OSQA. You'll probably have to convert the SE dumps to fit the OSQA schema, I suggest taking a look at the two schemas first.

Comment: Also, [what you're making already exists](http://www.rugatu.com/)

Comment: @Bart there is an inherent problem with importing users and scores, though. That's never been on the menu AFAIK

Comment: @Pekka웃 I wasn't really referring to that. This question was closed before and was somehow seen as inappropriate, which it really isn't.

Answer (score 4):

OSQA has a [migration tool](http://meta.osqa.net/questions/5322/how-do-i-access-the-stackexchange-migration-tool) for Stack Exchange data dumps. That will allow you to export questions. User accounts, badges, and reputation counts are not part of the public data AFAIK, and can't be reused by third parties.

I'm not sure whether Stack Exchange publishes data dumps for beta sites, though.

Comment: Accounts, badges and rep counts are not part of the data dump, but a company like OSQA can easily whip up a little app that uses the API to fill in the gaps. Eventually, except for "Real Name", "Email" and "Open ID" fields, everything else should be doable.